How can I convert xlog(u(x)) into a concave function, given u(x) is concave w.r.t. x?
How can I convert xlog(u(x)) into a concave function, given u(x) is concave w.r.t. x?
Tried subtituting x with other functions e.g. x=log(y) etc. and prove the joint concavity w.r.t. x and y, but failed.
Is there anyways to construct such a function?

Is u(x) everywhere positive? x.log(1+u(x)) might stand a chance...

Yes it is. Could you further elaborate how would I turn x.log(1+u(x)) into a concave one?@MartinBrown
